# OWASP ZAP main tabs are hidden

Tags: owasp, zap

I have lost the 'Quick Start' tab from my zap application, along with a few other tabs I'm sure. How do I get these to show again? I'm not sure what I did to hide them in the first place.

Thanks

Comment: Oh wait, I found it! View - Show Tab

Comment: Bizzare that it took me an hour to find that. Sorry folks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably clicked on the 'x' button on the relevant tab which hides it.
Note we do have a ZAP user group just for these sort of questions: http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Answer (score 0):

I am using OWASP ZAP 2.3.1. For viewing the "Quick Start" tab do the following steps:
1. Go to View menu -> Show tab
2. Click Quick Start tab

Comment: Current version of ZAP is 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed quick scan addon.

You can install it again from Addon >> Marketplace >> Quick start

Let me know if this works

Thanks